# tshark unable filter mac address during live capture

Tags: wireshark, tshark

I am trying to capture packet using tshark and I want to add filter for wlan source address , so I tried below three steps but none of them worked .

```
 ubuntu:/home/test$  tshark -i mon0 -w /tmp/test11.pcap -a duration:15 -R 
 (wlan.sa == 3e:52:82:c1:2e:a9)"
```

***tshark: -R without -2 is deprecated. For single-pass filtering use -Y.***

```
 ubuntu:/home/test$  tshark -i mon0 -w /tmp/test11.pcap -a duration:15 -Y "
 (wlan.sa == 3e:52:82:c1:2e:a9)"
```

***tshark: Display filters aren't supported when capturing and saving the captured packets.***

```
ubuntu:/home/test$  tshark -i mon0 -w /tmp/test11.pcap -a duration:15 -2R "
(wlan.sa == 3e:52:82:c1:2e:a9)"
```

***tshark: Live captures do not support two-pass analysis.***

How to add the filter for wlan address

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using tshark in capture mode (vs. offline, on a capture file), so you need to use a capture filter, which have their own syntax (same as tcpdump as far as I know). There's no flag needed for capture filter (no `-R` or `-Y`):

```
tshark -i mon0 -w /tmp/test11.pcap -a duration:15 ether src 3e:52:82:c1:2e:a9
```